# Stop two rectangles from intersecting

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

[image: Two Rectangles]

This little world contains a person (blue rectangle), and a tree (large green rectangle). The person can be controlled by pressing the up, down, left, right keys on the keyboard. The blue rectangle only moves when the keys are pressed. The blue rectangle must not get off the map (i.e. must not get out of the grey area), and must not overlap the green rectangle.

I am aware of the method to prevent the blue rectangle from getting off the grey area:

```
if (blueRect.rightEdge >= (canvas.width - 1)) {
    // Don't allow going further to the right
    // But allow going up, down, and to the left
}

// Check the same thing for the other sides of the grey area
```

What I am not sure is how to prevent the two rectangles from intersecting.
[image: Two Rectangles]

In the picture above, how do I "disable" going to the right (to prevent an intersection)? I would still like to be able to go up, down, and left.

Comment: Learn about collision detection? I'm sure there are sufficient tutorials and resources you can find using the search engine of your choice

Comment: @UnholySheep The problem is that most tutorials teach how to detect intersections. I don't need to detect intersections. I need to prevent intersections.

Comment: That is called "collision resolution" - which is the next step after detecting a collision. If you want to prevent an intersection you first need to determine that one will happen if you move your object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are dealing with is called [collision detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection).  I don't believe there is a simple answer that always applies.

However, in your case, because you have simple rectangles, you can check to see if any one of the four corners of the *SMALLER* rectangle is inside the *LARGER* rectangle.

If you don't know which is smaller, and which is larger, you could check in both directions (i.e. is rectangle A's corner inside rectangle B, and then if rectangle B's corner is inside rectangle A).  Make sure you use >= and <= to catch that pesky boundary condition.

Perhaps something like this is appropriate (pseudocode):

```
nextLocation = translate(rectangleA, "up")
if (isIntersecting(rectangleB, nextLocation)) {
    error("collision!")
} else {
    rectangleA = nextLocation
}
```

Comment: But wouldn't your suggested method produce an intersection? The problem with an intersection is that if I press the right button and collide with something, there is no way to know that the right way to get out of the mess is by pressing the left button.

Comment: You want to detect if the requested move would result in an intersection.  If it does, you disallow that move based on "collision."  Don't forget -- this is not a simple subject you are dealing with.